# Disable & enable Google Play system apps or 3rd Party apps in android

Tags: android, apk, root

As we known, 
On devices running Android 4.0 and higher, you can disable pre-installed Google Play system apps through your device Settings. After a system app has been disabled, it will be hidden on your device.

steps for [Disable & enable Google Play system apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3123922?hl=en-IN)

**Disable pre-installed system apps**

**1.** Go to your device's Settings menu.

**2.** Select Apps.

**3.** Touch the system app you’d like to disable.

**4.** Select Disable.

**Re-enable pre-installed system apps**

If you’ve disabled an app and would like to enable it, you can find and re-enable the app using the following steps:

**1.** Go to Settings on your device.

**2.** Swipe to view the list of All apps.

**3.** Scroll to the bottom of the list to view disabled system apps.

**4.** Touch the system app from the list that you’d like to enable.

**5.** Select Enable.

Once a system app has been re-enabled, it can be viewed and opened from your main apps screen.

but i want to **Disable & enable Google Play system apps & 3rd Party apps in android** programmetically.

I have rooted android device .

I want to do this for only rooted device not for non-rooted device.

**how I disable  & enable system ?** if you have any idea then please tell me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enable or disable system apps programmatically.
Though you can open app info screen in settingform where user can disable the app.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable app:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting("disableapp.package", PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

Enable app:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting("enableapp.package", PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Of course it need system privilege to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to disable and enable Google Play system apps or third-party applications in Android:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting("disableapp.package",PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Try edting your answer with more explanation please.